# Триггер google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

прошу прощения если данный вопрос уже прозвучал.
Я подготовил пример в отдельной [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1benDuyOamJ3U2qPMsIHSQNp7T02Q4K1HhMbMabgKTZU/edit?usp=sharing)
*(доступ на редактирование закрыт, скопируйте файл на свой google drive чтобы протестировать код)*

Как мне нужно чтобы это работало:
Каждый 3й день с 1 до 2 часов ночи в ячейке А1 должен поменяться "Рабочий 1" на "Рабочий 2". Эта функция (workShift) работает идеально, если я запускаю её вручную.

Проблема:

1. Триггер срабатывает раньше времени
2. Триггер срабатывает, но функция не выполняется по неизвестной ошибке: We're sorry, the JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error. Error code INTERNAL.

Настройки триггера, которые я получаю после запуска функции trigger

```js
function trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("workShift")
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(1)
    .everyDays(3)
    .create();
}
```

[image: Скриншот настроек триггера]

я буду очень благодарен любой помощи и подсказке.
Спасибо!

Comment: Обсуждение текущей проблемы https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/EqOTJqt7pg0 Что со временем исполнения - не понятно, т.к. только владелец триггера может видеть его полные настройки. Добавьте описание и скриншоты.

Comment: @contributorpw спасибо за Ваш ответ.

Comment: @contributorpw что-нибудь изменилось за прошедшее время? гугл так и молчит? (если Вы в курсе)

Comment: Насколько я знаю, было починено, но иногда еще возникают ошибки.

Comment: @contributorpw т.е. пользоваться не советуете? я то уже нашел для себя выход, но вдруг еще потребуется использовать такой триггер... а он снова не работает. (спасибо за ответы!)

Comment: Система стабильна. Для обычного пользователя она предоставляется "как есть". Поэтому некоторые баги могут присутствовать какое-то время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему я получал ошибку я так и не разобрался, возможно всему виной часовой пояс аккаунта, который не совпадал с поясом таблицы (или наоборот), но я нашел обходной путь чтобы реализовать то, что хотел:

1. На новом листе пришлось создать [календарь](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1benDuyOamJ3U2qPMsIHSQNp7T02Q4K1HhMbMabgKTZU/edit?usp=sharing):
   (доступ на редактирование закрыт, скопируйте файл на свой google drive чтобы протестировать код)

[image: календарь]

2. пишем небольшой скрипт по изменению "рабочего", по цвету ячейки текущей даты.

```js
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheet_WS = ss.getSheetByName(" work shifts (2021)");
let sheet_Main = ss.getSheetByName(' Main');

let worker_1 = "Рабочий 1"
let worker_2 = "Рабочий 2"
let worker_3 = "Рабочий 3"

function calendar() {
  let month;
  switch (new Date().getMonth().toString()) {
   case "0" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('B4:H9'); break;
   case "1" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('K4:Q9'); break;
   case "2" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('T4:Z9'); break;
   case "3" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('B12:H17'); break;
   case "4" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('K12:Q17'); break;
   case "5" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('T12:Z17'); break;
   case "6" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('B20:H25'); break;
   case "7" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('K20:Q25'); break;
   case "8" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('T20:Z25'); break;
   case "9" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('B28:H33'); break;
   case "10" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('K28:Q33'); break;
   case "11" : month = sheet_WS.getRange('T28:Z33'); break;
  }

  // Ищем текущую дату и устанавливаем ей красную рамку
  let cell;
  for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= 6; j++){
    if(month.getValues()[i][j] == new Date().getDate().toString()){
    month.setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)  
    cell = sheet_WS.getRange(month.getRow() + i, month.getColumn() + j) // Координаты ячейки в календаре
    cell.setBorder(true,true,true,true,null,null,'red',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)
    break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Меняем "рабочего", определив цвет ячейки текущей даты
  if(cell.getBackground() == "#c9daf8"){
  if(sheet_Main.getRange('A1').getValue() != worker_1){
  sheet_Main.getRange('A1').setValue(worker_1)}}
  else if(cell.getBackground() == '#ead1dc'){sheet_Main.getRange('A1').setValue(worker_3)}
  else{if(sheet_Main.getRange('A1').getValue() != worker_2){sheet_Main.getRange('A1').setValue(worker_2)}}
}
```

3. триггер устанавливаем на запуск функции каждый день с 1 до 2 часов

Может быть код можно было написать более элегантно, но если работает, не трогай =)